# Modern Warfare 2: Prestige Titles

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I've recently picked up on MW2 again and am planning to go prestige soon-ish. I've stayed at lvl 70 to complete achievements like headshots etc (as I already had quiet some progress on them).

I know there are prestige specific titles, some are related to a specific prestige stage. My question now is: can I level to prestige 10, 70 and then start working on my achievements, collecting **all** titles?

I would expect getting achievements on a higher prestige would account for the achievement on a lower prestige? (like if you complete the single player campaign on veteran, you also get the achievement for completing the campaign on regular and hardened)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Master Sargeant of the Shooter Seargent Shooter Person To The Max.

Comment: are you talking achievements as in xbox? since there are no online achievements for modern warfare to collect. if you just mean achievements as titles and challenges, then im sorry :P.

Comment: @Andy yes I mean achievements as in titles and challenges :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should have absolutely no issues doing that.  I believe you should have most all of the Prestige related titles already, but I haven't gotten to 10 yet myself.

For more information on what you need to do to get the titles, the Call of Duty Wiki on Wikia has a [full list of all Titles](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Callsigns/Modern_Warfare_2_Titles).  The Prestige related Titles are listed with a green background.